# camry 2004 cranks but takes a long time to start

Tags: toyota, starting, camry

I have toyota camry 2004, it cranks but takes a long time to start,I changed self starter and fuel pump but nothing changed.
Can anyone advise plz.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the fuel pressure over time? One of two things could be happening: 1) the car may not be maintaining fuel pressure after engine shutdown (possible fuel pressure regulator issue); 2) leaky injectors. The system should maintain most of the fuel pressure for some time after shutdown. On the order of 24 hours. If it drops fuel pressure fast, one of these two things could be happening. You can also try bumping the starter without starting it to get the fuel pump to energize a second time, then try to start it and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I had this problem with my corolla 1992, turn out to be distributor problem. During cranking, system voltage drops and this somehow reduce the high voltage output. After 5th crank attempt the engine will start probably due to higher cylinder temperature at that moment ignite fuel easily. My foreman replaced the distributer and no problem since then.

Comment: Is there a difference when the engine is cold vs. when it is hot?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 , what you mean by bumping the starter without starting it?

Comment: @soosaisteven - To turn the key just enough to *begin* to engage the starter, but not enough to actually start the engine. Doing so usually causes the fuel pump to re-energize for a few seconds, which will build more fuel pressure in the system.